# Continuous function $\rho: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$ with boundedness condition is surjective

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\rho: \mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}^n$ be a continuous function. Assume that there is an $M > 0$ such that $|| \rho(x)-x || < M$ for each $x \in \mathbf{R}^n$. Prove that $\rho$ is surjective.

The proposition is easy to show for $n = 1$. For arbitrary $n$, I have been able to show that if $x_0 \not \in$ im $\rho$, then there is a $r > 0$ such that $\overline{B_r(x_0)} \cap$ im $\rho = \emptyset.$

Comment: It’s impossible to know what tools/theorems you have to use.

Comment: @TedShifrin If it helps, the problem is from a PhD qualifying exam.

Comment: Then probably some basic ideas from algebraic topology may be useful. Homotopy? Brouwer fixed point theorem?

Comment: How did you prove it for $n=1$?

Comment: @azif00 The case $n=1$ follows by IVP of continuous functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider $$f(x)=x-\rho(x)+y$$ Note that $\lVert f(x)-y\rVert<M$ regardless of $x$. In fact we can change this inequality to "$\leq$". Thus $f$ maps the closed ball around $y$ of radius $M$ to itself. Therefore by the Brouwers fixed point theorem there is $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$, i.e. $\rho(x_0)=y$. So $\rho$ is surjective, by the arbitrary choice of $y$.